# Core Data many-to-many relationship. Saving an array of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a GameData entity which is meant to store an array of strings. So I made a 'Value' Entity which has a value string attribute and made a many-to-many relationship between the two entities.

To save the data I use the following code:

```
//Save values
NSMutableSet* values = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for(NSString* n in gameData.values){
    NSManagedObject *val = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Value"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [val setValue:n forKey:@"value"];
    [values addObject:val];
}
[gd setValue:values forKey:@"values"];
```

The gameData.values array is currently empty so the code never actually goes into the for loop...but for some reason it crashes at this line `[gd setValue:values forKey:@"values"]` with the following error.

```
-[__NSSetM managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f0485d0
```

Where or how am I sending a `managedObjectContext` selector to my values NSMutableSet??

Comment: why are you saving the values in gd ? where as, they are just the insert models... and where have you defined the relation with the other model in this piece of code ?

Comment: The relationships are defined in the .xcdatamodeld file. And `gd` is my NSManagedObject so I think that's were they need to be stored.

Comment: I have tried your code with a many-to-many relationship, and it worked as expected, without crash. Do you use NSManagedObject subclasses for your entities? If yes, can you show the contents of their .h files? Can you set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C exceptions" and show the stack backtrace of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to check whether the type of your entity is "To Many".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, thats why i am creating an answer.

Why don't you create the subclass for your entities using the xcode and import their header files and use code like below

```
    //Save values
    //NSMutableSet* values = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init]; -- No Need of this

    for(NSString* n in gameData.values){
        Value *val = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Value"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [val setValue:n];  // set your string
        [val setGame:gd]; //  set the game relation here. you can do this, if you have
```

configured inverse relations. If no create inverse relationship it will be helpful.

```
    } 
    //[gd setValue:values forKey:@"values"]; you don't need this.
```

Now just save the context. Everything should be fine. This is much more cleaner than your way.  I have never ever used key value for accessing core data entity properties because, it will be confusing and error prone as you have to remember the exact spelling of the property, and it wont throw any error if you have used wrong spelling or wrong key.

i think you should look at [core data programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1)

**Edit:** If your GameEntity stores array of strings then one to many relationship is just enough. You need many to many only if GameEntity has many Strings and Each Strings i.e. Value entity also has many GameEntity. In that case the above code slightly changes.

Instead of

```
[val setGame:gd];
```

You need to use

```
[val addGameObject:gd];
```

Comment: You're right that it doesn't need a many-to-many relationship. I however got it to work just by copying-and-pasting code from one of my previous projects...I can't tell what the difference was though, looks the same to me.